# What is Pages (from D7 and D8) replaced with in D9?

Tags: migrations, 9

I'm working on a D9 project that we just migrated from D7, but there doesn't exist a `admin > structure > pages` link. What was this replaced with? Same with Panels, I still see Panels as a Content Type, but what about a structure?

All I could find online was "How to create a Basic Page". I want more than a basic page, I want to structure pages together.

Comment: I have never seen a "Pages" under structure. Must be a contributed module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *admin/structure/pages* route is handled by the *Page Manager* module, which is included in the Drupal 7 version of the [Chaos Tool Suite (ctools)](https://www.drupal.org/project/ctools) project.

> [image: screenshot]

For Drupal 8 and Drupal 9, it's a separate project: the [Page Manager](https://www.drupal.org/project/page_manager) project. The route is handled by the *Page Manager UI* module that is part of that project. Installing only the *Page Manager* module doesn't make that route available.

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thanks! Surprised this still isn't included in Chaos Tools...

Comment: For what I recall, part of the original code in the *Page Manager* has been incorporated in Drupal core. That's why the *Page Manager* module was separated from the *Chaos Tool Suite (ctools)* project. It was not made a different project to then merge the projects back.